# Usar For In para verificar que un objeto tiene una propiedad

Tags: javascript

me podrían ayudar con el siguiente ejercicio:

Estoy intentando verificar que dado un objeto

```
var perrito = {
    nombre : "Yuki",
    edad: 1
}
```

Con una función que reciba como parámetro el objeto y el nombre de la propiedad, pueda verificar si el objeto contiene esta propiedad. Sé que es más fácil con hasOwnProperty pero no puedo hacerlo funcionar con for in.

```
function verificar (objeto, propiedad){
    var arr = []
    for(key in objeto){
        if(key == [propiedad]){
            arr.push(key)
        } 
        console.log(arr)
    }
    console.log(arr[propiedad])
    if (arr.includes([propiedad]) === true) {
        return "Sí contiene la propiedad"
    } else {
        return "No contiene la propiedad"
    }
}
```

`console.log(verificar(perrito, "edad"))`

Me retorna "No contiene la propiedad", a pesar de que edad sí es una propiedad del objeto

Creo que el problema está en el includes, ya que me retorna false a pesar de que arr sí contiene dicha propiedad

¿Estoy usando mal el includes? ¿Hay otra forma de verificar que exista aparte de hasOwnProperty? Gracias!

Comment: Hola, el problema está en que `propiedad` no debería tener `[]` ya que al colocarlos estás comparando un string contra un array. El único lugar en donde es correcto tenerlos es en el console.log.

Comment: No hay necesidad del ciclo -ni la función-, basta con `'edad' in perrito`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efectivamente, el problema está en el includes. Le estas preguntando si el array contiene `[propiedad]`, es decir, un array con el string "edad" en su interior. Pero en realidad lo que tenes que buscar es solo el string, es decir `includes(propiedad)` en vez de `includes([propiedad])`. Permiso, use los datos de mi perro

```js
var perrito = {
  nombre: "Greta", 
  edad: 10
}
function verificar (objeto, propiedad){
    var arr = []
    for(key in objeto){
        if(key == [propiedad]){
            arr.push(key)
        } 
    }
    if (arr.includes(propiedad) === true) {
        return "Sí contiene la propiedad"
    } else {
        return "No contiene la propiedad"
    }
}
console.log(verificar(perrito, "edad"))
```

Y podes hacerla un poco mas corta asi

```
function verificar (objeto, propiedad){
    let encontrado = false;
    for(key in objeto){
        if(key == propiedad){
            encontrado = true;
            break;
        } 
    }
    
    return encontrado ? "Sí contiene la propiedad" : "No contiene la propiedad"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un error en estas 2 líneas de código:

```js
if (key == [propiedad]) { ... }
```

---

```js
if (arr.includes([propiedad]) === true) { ... }
```

Aquí debes quitar los corchetes ya que estás queriendo buscar un string, entonces [**`includes()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) espera una cadena como parámetro y los corchetes están que convierten la cadena en un array.

En pocas palabras, estás queriendo buscar un array `[propiedad]` dentro de tu array `arr`, y lo que necesitas es buscar un string en tu array, es por eso que debes quitar los corchetes para que sea cadena. Código:

```js
var perrito = {
  nombre: 'Yuki',
  edad: 1,
};

function verificar(objeto, propiedad) {
  var arr = [];
  for (key in objeto) {
    if (key == propiedad) {
      arr.push(key);
    }
  }
  if (arr.includes(propiedad) === true) {
    return 'Sí contiene la propiedad';
  } else {
    return 'No contiene la propiedad';
  }
}

console.log(verificar(perrito, "edad"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Como ya te mencionaron (en los comentarios y en la otra respuesta), el problema está en que estás comparando un array en lugar de un string al colocar `[]`. De hecho, viendo tu solución se ve que después no haces nada con el array, así que tampoco tiene mucho sentido hacer uso del mismo. Basta con comparar si la `key` es igual a la `propiedad` que buscas y retornar el resultado.

```js
const perrito = {
    nombre : "Yuki",
    edad: 1
}

function verificar(objeto, propiedad) {
    for(const key in objeto){
        if(key === propiedad){
            return "Sí contiene la propiedad"
        } 
    }
    return "No contiene la propiedad"
}

console.log(verificar(perrito, "edad"))
console.log(verificar(perrito, "peso"))
```

La pregunta hace mención a usar `for...in`, pero solo como extra, tampoco sería necesario hacer uso del mismo ya que si solo quieres validar el primer nivel, bastaría con hacer lo siguiente:

```js
const perrito = {
    nombre : "Yuki",
    edad: 1
}

function verificar(objeto, propiedad) {
  return objeto[propiedad] ? 'Si existe la propiedad' : 'No existe la propiedad';
}

console.log(verificar(perrito, "edad"))
console.log(verificar(perrito, "peso"))
```